# Navigate to a folder in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a folder named

```
degtf-ithuju\syntg-backup\@GMT-2022.02.18-02.00.10
```

The last 6 characters of this folder changes daily. I need to navigate to it.

I created the string up to `degtf-ithuju\syntg-backup\@GMT-2022.02.18`. Now I need to use a wild card so that the path is reachable and I can get the content of the

```
degtf-ithuju\syntg-backup\@GMT-2022.02.18-02.00.10
```

folder.

So I hardcoded `degtf-ithuju\syntg-backup\@GMT-2022.02.18` in a variable but now how do I add that remaining name to it? It can't be hard coded.

```
$YD = (get-date -format "yyyy.MM.dd").ToString()
$v1= "C:\Ps\degtf-ithuju\syntg-backup\@GMT-"
$v2= $v1 + $YD
$v2
```

I Tried * and % but its not working.

```
cd c:\Ps\$v2% or cd C:\Ps\$v*
```

Up to `$V2` it is fine, but after that it's not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The following (partially commented) script shows possible approach:

```
$YD = Get-Date -format "yyyy.MM.dd-"
$v1= "C:\Ps\degtf-ithuju\syntg-backup\@GMT-"
$v2= $v1 + $YD + '*'

$fldrs = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $v2 -Directory)
switch ($fldrs.Count){
    0 { "no such folder: $v2"
        # create one as follows?
        $fldrName = $v1 + (Get-Date -format "yyyy.MM.dd-hh.mm.ss")
        New-Item -Path $fldrName -ItemType Directory -WhatIf
        break
      }
    1 { $fldrName = $fldrs[0].FullName
        "found folder: $fldrName"
        break
      }
    Default {
        "found $($fldrs.Count) folders: $v2"
        # choose one e.g. the last one as follows?
        $fldrName = $fldrs[-1].FullName
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

- [Array subexpression operator @( )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--): *Returns the result of one or more statements as an array. The result is always an array of 0 or more objects.* Used in `$fldrs = @( … )`.
- [Subexpression operator $( )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#subexpression-operator--): *Returns the result of one or more statements. … For example, to embed the results of command in a string expression.* Used in `"found $($fldrs.Count) folders: $v2"`.
- [about_Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch)
- [*Powershell-3.0* accepts the `-Directory` switch parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0) used in `Get-ChildItem -Path $v2 -Directory`